# Java Google Cloud Endpoints API UTF-8 Unicode Chinese Characters Generated Android Client?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using Google Cloud Endpoints API on the Google App Engine Server, and the generated client on a native Android app, to post and get data.

This has been working fine, except that non-ASCII characters, like Chinese characters, as well as characters like “ and ”, are displayed as weird characters, such as â. I must say I don't really know my way around the generated code, or do I want to tamper with them.

This issue occur on both localhost and the GAE server.

Any ideas how to enable UTF-8/unicode for data transmission?

Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem, and parcial solution is encode before of sent to server. I can not find other solution.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17192500/858289

Try adding a Charset.forName("UTF-8") argument to your InputStreamReader.