# set request/response encoding to UTF-8 to store text in app engine data store

Tags: android, google-app-engine, encoding, utf-8, google-cloud-endpoints

In my android app, I am saving some data in the local file system and retrieving the same to display back in an android activity. I am using UTF-8 format to store the text hence I am able to save and display files in multiple languages. This works fine. My app is also connected to google app engine and I am using the google app engine data store to store some data. In some cases I am saving my text to app engine datastore and retrieving them back. In the process I am noticing that there is no way to specify  UTF-8 encoding for my test while saving. Is there any way to ensure the UTF-8 formatting is used in the process of saving and retrieving the text from app engine data store?

Added sample code below for datastore inserrt operation

```
    public class EndpointsInsertUpdateQuizContentTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Long>{
    protected Long doInBackground(Context... contexts){
        Quizcontenttableendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Quizcontenttableendpoint.Builder(
        AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { } });
        Quizcontenttableendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(endpointBuilder).build();
        try{
            //get local file content into a string
            int ch;
            StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");
            FileInputStream fis;
            //String quizContentString;
            fis = getBaseContext().openFileInput(selectedQuiz);
            while( (ch = fis.read()) != -1)
                fileContent.append((char)ch);
            String quizContentString = new String(fileContent);

                QuizContentTable quizContentTable = new QuizContentTable();
                quizContentTable.setQuizKey(quizKey);
                quizContentTable.setQuizContent(quizContentString);

                quizContentResult = endpoint.insertQuizContentTable(quizContentTable).execute();
        }   
        catch(Exception e){
            errMsg=e.toString();}
        return (long) 0;
    }
    private ProgressDialog pdia;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){ 
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdia = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        pdia.setMessage("Loading");
        pdia.show();    
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result1) {
        pdia.dismiss();

}
```

I searched for similar issues in other stackoverflow queries, and some of them hinted towards setting the UTF-8 encoding during the request and response. I am not sure where to set that in my android app. In the appengine code I can only specify/edit the entities and corresponding fields and their data types. I then generate the corresponding end point library in my project. Where do I set the encoding for request/response for the app engine?

Comment: You might want to consider storing your text in Google Cloud Storage instead of App Engine.  You can write utf-8 text directly to GCS.

Comment: I am storing my data into the datastore in Google Cloud Storage only.

Answer (score 2):

Text strings are stored in the App Engine datastore as **unicode** strings, so no byte-encoding is applicable.

See, for example, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Properties_and_value_types -- a short text string (up to 500 unicode characters) maps to a `java.lang.String` (thus, unicode) and can be indexed; a long one (can't be indexed) maps to a https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Text and is also stored as unicode.

**However**, while the datastore supports Unicode, and thus text, directly, HTTP demands the use of **bytes**, and thus requires proper encoding to send, and decoding back on receipt (whence the need for the `charset=` part in the Content-Type header).  Specifically,in HTTP (both requests and responses), the encoding is specified as a part of the **Content-Type** header: e.g,

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

In a servlet, such as used in the App Engine Java runtime, you set that header by calling the `setContentType` and `setCharacterEncoding` methods of the `ServletResponse` -- see e.g http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setCharacterEncoding(java.lang.String) .

As the OP clarifies in a comment that:

> non-English text to be stored in that [[`Text`]] field but while
>   displaying it back, the non-English text is lost and is displayed in
>   some weird way [[ as viewed in the App Engine console ]]

the likely cause of the problem is that the request sent to App Engine is not being properly serialized as UTF8 bytes and with the `Content-Type` as specified above.

Of course, the header only applies to the request's **body**.  To send Unicode text as part of the **query string** (e.g, in an HTTP `GET`), the further `%HH` encoding of each (UTF-8 encoded) byte is needed.  So, for example, to send значение -- which in UTF-8 becomes \xd0\xb7\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5 -- you'd visit e.g

```
http://appid.appspot.com/x?y=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5
```

Comment: In such a case then why is any multilingual (non English but Unicode supported) text not displaying properly in the data store. I can view the stored data using the app engine console and I can see that the language encodings are getting lost.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the explaination. My query however remains. I am storing some text as a data type "Text" in my entity. As I understand, it should be stored and retreived as Unicode. In that case if I pass on any Unicode supported language as the conent of that field then it should be displayed the same way in my app. I am however noticing that I am entering some non-English text to be stored in that field but while displaying it back, the non-English text is lost and is displayed in some weired way, for example "à¤¦à¥"

Comment: @user1938357, are you setting the proper Content Type header in the request you send to App Engine, and serializing that text appropriately?  Text is indeed *stored* and *retrieved* as Unicode (the datastore supports that), but HTTP demands a stream of bytes, and thus proper encoding to send, and decoding back on receipt (whence the need for the `charset=` in the Content-Type header).  Editing the answer to make this point more sharply.

Comment: I am using my app as the back end to simply store and retrieve the text data stored in the google app engine data store. As you are aware this is achieved using the end point library which can be automatically generated in eclipse from any app engine project one creates. I assume the request/response to the app engine is done via http, however I am not sure if I can find out where in my app engine code that happens. Maybe that’s where I can specify UTF-8 encoding to be used.

Comment: @user1938357, if you're using Cloud Enpoints, why not add the google-cloud-endpoints tag?  Then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167475/messed-up-character-encoding-with-android-gae-cloud-endpoints/17192500#17192500 and just add an explicit charset as the poster there did.

Comment: Added the tag. Also can you please let me know where in my end point code do I add the explcit charset.

Comment: @user1938357, have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167475/messed-up-character-encoding-with-android-gae-cloud-endpoints as I recommended?  Seems pretty clear to me about where to set the 'utf8' explicitly.

Comment: I might sound very naive here, but I am not sure where do I put that code. The end point library is generated autoomatically and I just use that in my app. Please refer sample code where I do the insert operation to an entity in data store.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue. The problem was that I had missed out UTF encoding while reading the file content into the string. Replaced the filereading part in my code above with the below code

> ```
>           String str;
>             StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");
>             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getBaseContext().openFileInput(selectedQuiz), "UTF-8"));
>             while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)
>                 fileContent.append(str);
>             String quizContentString = new String(fileContent);
>             in.close();
> ```